# Make elements of a select box draggable to a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, struts2

**Scenario**

I have a JSP Page where i am populating a select box with values (I am using struts 2 framework)

**Problem**

I need to make the the elements of the select box draggable to a text area on the page.

**Tried:**

1. I can't use JSON, because it needs JSON return from action.  Neither struts tags of s:select has draggable()
2. draggable function using javascript seems to be the solution, but somehow only div and div /li elements seems draggable, whereas here the list is not in div.
3. I have a tinymce as the text area where the selected items to be dropped.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are new to writing in English too!

Comment: 1. You can return json from actions. 2. So put it in div. Overall very unclear. Try to explain what are you trying to achieve and post some code that you've tried.

Comment: The attributes `draggable="true"` or `drappable="true"` enable Drag & Drap functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the response Aleksandr and Roman. You guy's are right on the point about json and using it, but since the application i work on,has many templates  in one action class and the return of the result  is  not set in  xml as Json return. So i had to go with the current options. And i found s: iterator to be helpful in this regard

Comment: Mr.Praveen , I am good with my English and i never saw any problem with  it, so haven't my tutors. Editing the message to a form that is comprehensible to an elementary format , means only that it is rendered as an easy read for everyone and not to be misunderstood as a novice for the language. Now the next time, i expect you make a productive comment ,which helps the community and the person who posted!!!

Comment: So you've resolved your issue? If yes then post your solution as an answer and accept it. If no then -> Try to explain what are you trying to achieve and post some code that you've tried.